# Linear Algebra: Finite V.S., compositions, bijections.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, linear-transformations

Let $\phi: E \rightarrow E$ be injective linear map on a finite dimensional vector space such that there exists $f:E \rightarrow E$ with $f \circ \phi (x)=x$, $\forall x \in E$. Prove that $\phi$ is a bijection and $f = \phi^{-1}$.

*My Attempted proof:*

**A.** Suppose $ran{\phi} \neq x$, for some $x \in E$.
  So, there exists an $x \in E$ that is not mapped by $\phi$.
  Let $q$ be this element.

there exists a function, $g:E \rightarrow E$ such that...

*...and this is where I am stuck.  So I tried starting again...*

Suppose $\phi$ is not surjective. Then, there $\exists x \in E$ that is not mapped by $\phi$. Let $q$ denote this element.

Since $q \in E$, $f \circ \phi (q) = q$, by given.

$\iff f^{-1} (f \circ \phi(q)) = f^{-1} q$
   $\iff \phi (q) = f^{-1}(q) = a$ for some $a \in E$.

And this fails at accomplishing surjectivity.

**B.** WTS: $f = \phi^{-1}$.

$f \circ \phi(x) = x$ for all $x \in E$.

So, $f^{-1} (f \circ \phi(x)) = f^{-1} x$

$\phi(x)=f^{-1}(x)$

So, $\phi^{-1} = f$.

Clearly, I am having difficulty with the first part. I would also like to ask if the second part of this question is sufficiently proved. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The important part here is that the dimension is finite!

Comment: So, I can say that $\forall x \in E$, $f \circ \phi (x) = x$ and since E is finitely dimensional, all elements are mapped. So $ranf=E$. And since $\phi$ is 1 to 1, $y$ must have a specific $x \in E$ where $\phi(x)=y.$ And since $f(y)=x$ $\forall x \in E$, $f$ must be 1 to 1, leaving a conclusion that $\phi$ must map all of E, and thus is surjective. How does that sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A.  E is of a finite dimension, $\phi: E \rightarrow E$ is linear. 
  So, $dimE=dim(renge \phi)+dim(kern \phi)$
  $\phi$ is injective and linear. So, $\phi(0)=0$ 
  and $0$ is the only such element that maps to $0$. 
  So, $ker \phi = \{0\}$ and $dim (ker (\phi)) = 0
  So, $E = Range \phi$, and subjectivity follows.

B. $f (\phi (x)) = x$ $\forall x \in E$.
  $\iff f^{-1}(f( \phi (x))) = f^{-1}(x)$
  $\iff \phi(x) = f^{-1}(x)$.
  So, $f^{-1}= \phi$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for $g:V\to V$ linear and $\dim V$ finite we know that $\dim V = \dim \ker g + \dim \text{im } g$. What do we know about $\ker g$ if $g$ is injective?

Comment: We know that $ker(g)$ has an element in the vector space that maps to $0$, and since this map is linear, the unique value in the vector space that maps to the kernal, is in fact, $0$.